# How to upload an image through an API in laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, postman

(Image upload is working from post man but not  from laravel project )I'm using blade form and add ***enctype="multipart/form-data"*** to upload an image. I'm trying to upload using API. Here I just use image input field for understanding. I submit another information that I don't included here. All request successfully got and insert into database except image file. In API request there are no exist file!

```
<div class="card-body">
    <form class="form" id="employee_form" action="{{route('employee.add.post')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <div class="row m-2">
            <div class="col-12 row border my-3 pt-4 pb-2" style="background: #ECEDF3">
                  <div class="col-6 form-group">
                    <label class="control-label " for="avatar"><h5 class="h6">Photo <small>(<2mb,png,jpg) </small>                           </h5></label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="file" name="avatar" id="avatar"/>
                    <p id="avatar_validator_message" class="text-danger p-2"></p>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </form>
```

When I pass it into below funtion it receive the file perfectly. but when I pass it inside the API then it didn't receive any file. (API request receive all others). Below method exist in a controller where I submit the form and from here I call the API with request!

```
 public function add_employee_post(Request $request){
   //if ($request->hasFile('avatar')) {
    //     return 'here';
    // }
    // dd($request->file('avatar'));
    try{
      $http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
      $avatar = $request->avatar;
      
      $response = $http->post('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/employees/create',[

        //   'headers' => [
        //       'Authorization' => 'Bearer'.session()->get('token.access_token'),
        //   ],
          'query' =>[                  
              'avatar' => $avatar,                 
          ]
      ]);

      $result = json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
      return $result;       
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
       // throw $e;
        return response()->json([
            'result' => false,
            'message' => 'Something Error!'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Below Function is exist in API project's controller. here I just return request to see but there are no exist 'avatar' or any file (it receive all other request and perfectly work except file)

```
//To create new employee
public function create(Request $request){
    
    return $request;       

    $employee = new OsEmployee();
   
    if ($request->hasFile('avatar')) {

        $image = $request->file('avatar');
        $name = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $destinationPath = storage_path('/app/images/avatar');
        $image_full_path = '/app/images/avatar/'.$name;
        $image->move($destinationPath, $name);

        $employee->avatar = $image_full_path;
       // return $employee->avatar;
    }

        
   $employee->save();

   return response()->json([
    'result' => true,
    'message' => 'Employee information has been added successfully'
],201);


}
catch(\Throwable $e) {

    return response()->json([
        'result' => false,
        'message' => 'Something Error!'
    ]);
}

}
```

***When I submit from POSTMAN all works fine!*** What is the reason that I mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solve it. Actually I have to add image information and include multipart inside the request. [Here](https://stackcoder.in/posts/upload-file-from-frontend-server-guzzlehttp-to-rest-api-server-in-php-laravel) , that helps me.

```
    public function add_employee_post(Request $request){
   //if ($request->hasFile('avatar')) {
    //     return 'here';
    // }
    // dd($request->file('avatar'));
    try{
      $http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

          //avatar information
          $avatar_file               = request('avatar');
          $avatar_file_path          = $avatar_file->getPathname();
          $avatar_file_mime          = $avatar_file->getMimeType('image');
          $avatar_file_uploaded_name = $avatar_file->getClientOriginalName();
      
      $response = $http->post('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/employees/create',[

        //   'headers' => [
        //       'Authorization' => 'Bearer'.session()->get('token.access_token'),
        //   ],
          'query' =>[                  
             // 'avatar' => $avatar,                 
          ]
           'multipart' => [
                [
                    /** This is the actual fields name that you will use to access in API */
                'name'      => 'avatar',
                'filename' => $avatar_file_uploaded_name,
                'Mime-Type'=> $avatar_file_mime,

                /** This is the main line, we are reading from file temporary uploaded location  */
                'contents' => fopen($avatar_file_path, 'r'),
                ],
              ]
      ]);

      $result = json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
      return $result;       
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
       // throw $e;
        return response()->json([
            'result' => false,`enter code here`
            'message' => 'Something Error!'
        ]);
    }
}
```